# how to verify if it's minimal installation or Server with GUI

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, gnome, gui

I have a server on cloud with SSH access, I want to know if it's minimal installation (without GUI) or Server with GUI installation,
please note that I don't have console access to the server except SSH with sudoers access

OS: CentOS 6.10

I know about RHEL/CentOS 8 we can check the installed group but not have any idea how to determine on older versions of Linux i.e. RHEL/CentOS 6 & 7, ubuntu

Comment: Have you tried to check if Xorg or Wayland is installed ?
You can also check if the gdm service exists...

Comment: or any of `xdm`, `kdm`, etc Display Managers.